# Syntax: python smtplib not working in script

Tags: python, syntax, smtplib

I tried running the following code (named as `email.py`):

```
import smtplib    
GMAIL_USERNAME = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
GMAIL_PASSWORD = raw_input("Enter your password: ")    
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.login(GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/home/sourya/VProgramming/projects/email.py", line 6, in <module>
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

However, the code does run when I type it out in the interpreter.

What's wrong?

Comment: The code causing the problem is not the same as stated (you are importing import email.utils) which is not part of the first code snippet....

Comment: @user0815: it's not the OP that imports email.utils, it's the smtplib.py, if you read the stack trace carefully :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try renaming you script (to something other than `email.py`).

`email` is a Python module, but your script's name shadows it, and it can't be imported.

**Note:** Don't forget to remove `email.pyc` as well.

Comment: The AttributeError is related to the smtplib module, not the email module

Comment: @user0815: just try it out, Lev Levitsky is 100% correct. SMTPlib uses email underwater and name of the script breaks its own imports.

Comment: @user0815 Yep, that's strange. But you see that after `import email.utils` in `/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py` the traceback goes to `/home/sourya/VProgramming/projects/email.py` which shouldn't happen.

Comment: Nah, I just ran a few tests, @LevLevitsky you're correct. As long as there's an email.py in the vicinity that is not part of SMTPlib, it breaks, otherwise it works.

Comment: @favoretti Yeah, I reproduced it, too.

Comment: I copied the code to a new file named send_email.py, leaving the email.py there itself. It again threw the same error. It worked upon deleting the file email.py. Looks like files in the same directory shadow the imported modules as well.

Comment: @sourya Yep, I meant removing `email.py` from the folder.

Comment: @Lev Levitsky: Thank you! It feels wonderful to send email from command line. :-)