# python email script doesn't work on mac os x 10.9

Tags: python, smtp

I started trying to make a script to send emails using python, but nothing worked. I eventually got to the point where I just started copying and pasting email scripts and filling in my info. Still nothing worked. So i eventually just got rid of everything except this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
```

This still did not work. Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work? I'm sure its really simple.  I'm using mac os x 10.9 if that makes a difference. here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_email.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Comment: What does 'it does not work' mean in this case?

Comment: what output gives `import email; print email.__file__`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. can you explain?

Comment: @Chase execute the line I provided as a mean of debug. run  `/usr/bin/python -c "import email; print email.__file__"` and include resulting output in question

Comment: i tried that and got this:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_email.py", line 2, in <module>
    import email; print email.__file__
  File "/Users/incite3/email.py", line 2
    import email; print email.__file__?
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Chase you should run it from the shell exacltly as specified. What is the file "/Users/incite3/email.py"? Is it old name of  `the_email.py`?

Comment: I ran it exactly as you said:   $ /usr/bin/python -c "import email; print email.__file__"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/incite3/email.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named utils

Comment: @Chase do you have file `email.pyc` still in your folder `/Users/incite3/`? Remove it if yes, it is compliled email.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the name of your script from `email.py` to something else.  It is interfering with the Python standard library module of the same name, `email`.

Comment: Did you also remove any `email.pyc` file?  That is a compiled cache file that gets generated automatically by Python when you import a file.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Syntax: python smtplib not working in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102113/syntax-python-smtplib-not-working-in-script)

A user says that you have to remove email.py from the folder.